# What is the proper way of nesting resources in REST model?

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I'm designing a REST API of service and got stuck on proper way to nest resources.

Resources: partners, tickets, settings

Connections between resources:

- partner has many tickets,
- partner has set of settings,

Bussines logic:

- you can list all partners as anonymous user,
- you can add new ticket to specified partner as anonymous user,
- only partner can list his tickets,
- only partner can modify his tickets,
- only partner can list settings,
- only partner can modify settings,

What I did till now:

**Partner resources**

GET /partners - list all partners
GET /partners/:id - show details of the partner specified by :id parameter
GET /partners/:partner_id/tickets - list of partner's tickets
GET /partners/:partner_id/tickets/:id - details of the specified partner's ticket
POST /partners/:partner_id/tickets - saves new ticket
PUT /partners/:partner_id/tickets/:id - updates the ticket specified by :id parameter
GET /partners/:partner_id/settings - list partner's settings
PUT /partners/:partner_id/settings - update partner's settings

**Problem/Question**

Would it be proper way to split nested resources (tickets, settings) to seperate resources or duplicate them as seperate resources?

E.g.

GET /tickets/:id
POST /tickets
PUT /tickets/:id

GET /settings
PUT /settings

Answer (score 9):

[HATEOAS](http://www.slideshare.net/trilancer/why-hateoas-1547275):

`GET /partners/:partner_id/tickets` - list of partner's tickets, that is, returns a list of URIs, probably of the form `/tickets/:id`

`GET /partners/:partner_id/tickets/:id` - not needed

`POST /partners/:partner_id/tickets` - creates a ticket and associates to the partner, returns a 201 with the new URI, of the form `/tickets/:id`

Comment: Now I understand more. Thanks a lot :) But what about performance? Let assume that situation: you want to create list of tickets with some short informations. You have to request list of tickets for partner and after that request each ticket individualy. Am I right?

Comment: well, yes. or you could make the `/partners/:partner_id/tickets` list include some useful data for each ticket, not just the ticket's canonical URI.  For example, in JSON could be `[{href='/tickets/12',value=10,due='2013-08-13'},{href='/tickets/18',value=7,due='2013-09-02'}]`, so the client could immediately show some table, and GET/PUT the full ticket resource(s) for extra manipulation.

Comment: O.K. It's clear.

Comment: BTW. For /partners/:partner_id/tickets should docs be provided in partner or ticket resources section?

Comment: @Javier what about DELETE? `DELETE /tickets/:id`?

Comment: Bad question, of course `DELETE /tickets/:id`, since we don't have `/partners/:partner_id/tickets` anymore :P